# Events and signals in Qt's QGraphicsItem: How is this *supposed* to work?

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt4

Like other primitives in Qt, QGraphicsItems can handle mouse events and the like. Sweet! Now say I need for an event on one QGraphicsItem to be propagated to some other QGraphicsItems in the same scene. I can think of two ways that one might approach this:

---

#### (A) The Naive Approach - Signaling

**Concept :** Connect sibling QGraphicsItems together with signals. Event handlers on QGraphicsItem call emit()s that evoke coordinated responses on other QGraphicItems. This follows the general design pattern established throughout the Qt framework.

**Implementation :** For reasons that I do not fully grasp, QGraphicsItems cannot emit() signals. [It has been suggested](http://www.qtforum.org/article/31679/how-can-a-qgraphicsitem-signal-a-scene-update.html) that derived classes that also inherit from QGraphicsObject may be able to work around this. It seems to me, though, that the exclusion of emit() on QGraphicsItems was probably an intentional design decision on the part of the Qt devs and, therefore, multiple inheritance is probably not the Right Solution.

#### (B) Container-Level Event Handling

**Concept :** QGraphicsItems always exist in the context of a container of type QGraphicsScene. Events that in (A) were handled at the level of the QGraphicsItem are instead handled by an object inheriting from QGraphicsScene. This object also implements the logic for coordinating responses between sibling QGraphicsItems.

**Implementation :** QGraphicsScene definitely has the ability to handle events that would otherwise make their way down to QGraphicsItems. QGraphicsScene also provides the itemsAt() method for determining which of the things in it are affected by positional events, like mouse clicks. Still, building up considerable logic within a container class for coordinated action among containees feels like a failure to encapsulate properly. Bad practice? Maybe, but this seems to be the way it's done in at least [one official example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/graphicsview-diagramscene.html).

---

#### Questions

1. What's the Right Solution here? If not A or B, then is it something else that I haven't thought of?
2. Why did the Qt devs allow QGraphicsItems to receive events but not send signals? This seems like a major exception to the design pattern used throughout the framework.
3. An extension of this problem is communication between QGraphicsItems and higher-order container classes, like the main application. How is that meant to be addressed?

Comment: FYI: The use-case here is a resizable rectangle. It will have actuation points at each of its corners that, when clicked and dragged, cause the incident edges to move as well.

Comment: Wouldn't those edges be children of the rectangle and thus the parent should know of them?

Comment: I guess, yes, if I implemented (B) with a QGraphicsItemGroup or something similar.

Comment: No what I mean is that this situation sounds like you should be creating a custom subclass that has children items. Thus, the parent can act on the children directly instead of coordinating back up and down.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Signaling is not part of QGraphicItem because they do not inherit from QObjects. This was a design decision for performance reasons, to allow very large and fast scenes. If you decide you really need special cases for signals, QGraphicsWidget was created to fill this gap. It does inherit from QObject and lets you have a mixture of QWidget and QGraphicsItem functionality. Though it is recommended that you avoid this if your scenes are even moderately sizable.

Another option which might be relevant to your situation is to make use of the sceneEventFilter method. You can set one item to receive events for another and decide if they should be propagated or not: 
http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qgraphicsitem.html#sceneEventFilter
One item can be set as the filter for multiple objects. And it can identify each individual item and event to respond to.

Generally though you should make use of the scene for coordination across its objects. That is already the pattern being used for events (the scene coordinating delivery of all events to the items).

Also, it seems that your option A is not possible because QGraphicsItem does not even have an emit method. You would need to compose a QObject instance inside it as a member and use that to emit signals. Something along the lines of `myItem.qobject.emit()`. Otherwise, you would have to inherit your own completely custom one from QGraphicsObject

**Update 1**: Addressing your main comment update

Your specific situation is a rectangle with "hot corners". I would see this being a custom QGraphicsItem. You would probably subclass QGraphicsRectItem, and then compose the child hot corner items inside as children items (`setParentItem()`). Now your rectangle item knows about its children and can act on them directly. You could set the rectangle item to be the sceneEventFilter for the children and handle their events directly. No need to go back up to the scene. Let all this logic live in the class.

**Update 2**: Addressing your added question #3

Propagating communications up beyond the scene to QWidget's has a couple approaches I can think of:

1. This is a situation where you can consider if you want to use a QGraphicsObject subclass as your root item, and then compose the rest of your objects as children (the rect, then the hot corners as children of the rect). This would allow the object to emit signals. For clarity they would probably still be connected to the scene, and then the higher order container of the scene would connect to the scene. You would have to choose this approach on a case by case, depending on the complexity of your scene and whether the QGraphicsObject has any performance impact on it. You should probably avoid this if you will have a great number of these instances.
2. You could define a callback for your rect class, for which the scene can set. Either something like: `graphicsRect.resizedCallback` as an attribute, or a setter `graphicsRect.setResizedCallback(cbk)`. In your rect class, you would just call that when appropriate. If the callback it set, it can be used to call something on your scene directly. The rect class still has no knowledge of that logic. It just calls a callback.

Those are just some suggestions. I'm sure there are other ways.

Comment: @BrianTheLion: Yea thats what I was referring to doing for your situation. It uses event filters.

Comment: @jdl: Cheers! Any thoughts on my Question #3? It was a late addition. In the case of my resizable rectangle, I need to adjust a data structure in persistent storage each time the rectangle coordinates change.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest B unless you have relatively few QGraphicsItems. I believe QGraphicsItems are not QObjects because there is a certain amount of overhead associated with QObjects. The QGraphicsView framework was designed to allow fast insertion and deletion of many (e.g., thousands) QGraphicsItems into a scene, so a lighter-weight approach was preferred.

I would look to the concept of parenting in QGraphicsItems. QGraphicsItems can have parents and children, and this has several effects similar to parenting amongst QObjects. For example, if you move a parent QGraphicsItem, its children will move with it, and if you delete a parent, its children will be deleted. You can access a QGraphicsItem's parent using `QGraphicsItem::parentItem()`, and children using `QGraphicsItem::childItems()`. So, you can easily access sibling items like this:

```
QList<QGraphicsItem *> mySiblings = this->parentItem()->childItems();
```

Note that `mySiblings` includes `this`.