# QGraphicsObject needs explicit update to be redrawn

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a `QGraphicsPixmapItem` whose content change with mouse click. Everything works great when all interactive events are treated inside the class derived from `QGraphicsPixmapItem`:

```
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QMainWindow

class MyQGraphicsPixmapItem(QGraphicsPixmapItem):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.setNewImage()

  def setNewImage(self):
    im = np.random.randint(255, size=(256, 256), dtype=np.uint8)
    pix = QPixmap.fromImage(QImage(im, im.shape[1], im.shape[0], QImage.Format_Grayscale8))
    self.setPixmap(pix)

  def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self.setNewImage()

app = QApplication([])
window = QMainWindow()
window.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 400)
view = QGraphicsView()
scene = QGraphicsScene()
gpix = MyQGraphicsPixmapItem()
scene.addItem(gpix)
view.setScene(scene)
window.setCentralWidget(view)
window.show()
app.exec()
```

However, rather than having to treat events in the class, I would like to be able to treat them elsewhere, typically as callbacks. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10591172/9973879), two options are presented: using `QGraphicsObject`, or using scene event filters, which are strongly advised since the former is a heavy weight. However, AFAIU, scene event filters make events of a graphics item treated by another graphics item; I want something more general where a `QWidget` could treat the event. So I think in my case I need to use `QGraphicsObject`.

I made a simple modification to the script above to wrap the `QGraphicsPixmapItem` into a `QGraphicsObject`. However, what surprised me is that the image does not refresh when clicked.

```
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsObject, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QMainWindow

class MyQGraphicsObject(QGraphicsObject):

  def __init__(self, gpix):
    super().__init__(gpix)
    self.gpix = gpix
    self.setNewImage()

  def setNewImage(self):
    im = np.random.randint(255, size=(256, 256), dtype=np.uint8)
    pix = QPixmap.fromImage(QImage(im, im.shape[1], im.shape[0], QImage.Format_Grayscale8))
    self.gpix.setPixmap(pix)
    # self.update()  # needs to be uncommented to refresh

  def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self.setNewImage()

  def boundingRect(self):
    return self.gpix.boundingRect()

  def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
    return self.gpix.paint(painter, option, widget)

app = QApplication([])
window = QMainWindow()
window.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 400)
view = QGraphicsView()
scene = QGraphicsScene()
opix = MyQGraphicsObject(QGraphicsPixmapItem())
scene.addItem(opix)
view.setScene(scene)
window.setCentralWidget(view)
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Only if I manually add a `self.update()` does the image refresh. Of course that fixes the issue, but I have a feeling that should not be needed and I am using `QGraphicsObject` wrongly. Is that the case, or is the manual `update` actually needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct to call `update()` method.

---

#### TL; DR;

**In which cases do you need to call update?**

Whenever the developer needs to invoke the paint() method (or paintEvent on the widgets)

**Why in the case of QGraphicsPixmapItem it is not necessary to call it but in QGraphicsObject it is necessary?**

In QGraphicsPixmap `update()` method is being called and you can verify if [the source code](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsitem.cpp?h=dev#n9595) is revised:

```
void QGraphicsPixmapItem::setPixmap(const QPixmap &pixmap)
{
    Q_D(QGraphicsPixmapItem);
    prepareGeometryChange();
    d->pixmap = pixmap;
    d->hasShape = false;
    update();
}
```

In other words, in QGraphicsItem you no longer need to call it because the setPixmap method already does it, unlike QGraphicsObject which does not have it, so it is necessary to call update() to force the call of the paint method.